# jsonp.java.net: how to build with maven

Tags: java, json, maven

How do I use maven to build ?
I got code from [JSON Processing](https://jsonp.java.net/scm.html) and as I'm not familiar with maven I have (almost) no clue how to build the API and implementation jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you do:

```
mvn clean install
```

You can use also `verify` instead of `install` if you don't want to put the code in the local repo. Or `package` if you don't want to do package verifications.
The resulting package can be found in the `target` directories (only one if there is single module, multiple if there are multiple ones).

But sometimes projects have their own build procedures and enable certain profiles (with `-P` switch) or system properties (with `-D` switch) so it is best to consult the project README or similar.

Comment: Thanks, exactly the hint I needed.